# Magento API throws 500 error, says check exception log but nothing is there

Tags: php, magento, guzzle

I am using guzzle to test upload products with the Magento API. Whenever I run this script:

```
    <?php
require_once ('connparams.php');

try {
$response = $client->request('post', 'products', 
[
    "headers" => $headers,
    'body' => json_encode([
        'product' => 
            ['attribute_set_id' => 13],
            ['sku' => 12548],
            ['name' => 'widget'],
            ['price' => 1],
            ['type_id' => 'simple']
    ])
    ]);
}
```

I get the following error (which I'm outputting to a txt file with the catch block):

```
ERROR at: 06:50:15 pm | 500 | Internal Server Error | An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.
```

When I check the exception log in Magento, there is not a new entry. There are entries for exceptions when I test the API with swagger.

Comment: where is the catch part of try block in above code?

Comment: I didn't include it, but it writes the error to a txt file. I can post later if it's important, but I get the error no matter if I use try or catch.

Comment: show the catch, you can write dummy data in catch block